# How to automate disk checking in Windows?

Tags: maintenance, chkdsk

**Chkdsk is a very manual, technical solution**

Hard Drive checking in Windows reports a lot of unnecessary info, requiring that you read through it the chkdsk report, etc. Also chkdsk can't fix problems on an in-use files (like the Windows drive).  It seems like a little thing, but a non-technical user can't understand ChkDsk results and it takes even a technical user a minute to read through the report for *each* hard drive.

Even if I automated Chkdsk with the /x and /f options, I still have to *read* the report every day.

Is there a tool or built in service which will:

1. Automatically check all drives for errors
2. Report a simple "no problem" or "problem"
3. Ideally, schedule a repair operation on the next restart.
4. Bonus points: restart the computer to do the repair, and report all of that.

Comment: I've never heard of or known of anybody to run chkdsk on a regular schedule as part of a maintenance routine or procedure. You should run chkdsk when Windows informs you that there are issues that may be corrected by running chkdsk. Running it on a regular basis as a part of a maintenance routing or procedure doesn't strike me as being a good practice.

Answer (score 0):

There is a system command you can use to mark disk for automated checking on the next reboot:

```
FSUTIL dirty set <drive>:
```

For instance:

```
FSUTIL dirty set c:
```

Processing report is available via Event Viewer - System Log.

If you want an automated checks - put it as a task into Windows Task Scheduler.

If system founds disk problems it may mark volume as dirty(bad). To query dirty status use:

```
FSUTIL dirty query c:
```

Note that running FSUTIL require admin rights.

Alternatively you can adapt [this PowerShell script](https://www.poshsecurity.com/blog/2012/3/13/volume-health-checks-in-powershell.html) for your needs.

Answer (score 0):

For automation, you can create a new scheduled task to run a script which checks available volumes and runs chkdsk with appropriate parameters. Results are in Application Event log with "Chkdsk" as source and "26212" as Event Id. You can attach a task to this event and distribute both scheduled tasks with group policy.

Automating a repair operation and restart is not something I would do. Disk checks on large volumes take a lot of time and that means unpredictable downtime periods. Better to manually start it.

So, technically, it's possible, but I don't think it's something I would do.